# Camera rotation up and down limited to 45 degrees

Tags: c++, graphics, glut

I am trying to limit my camera rotation up and down so it can only be moved up to a max of 45 degrees and down to a max of 45 degrees.

```
 Vector3 forwards(0, 0, -1);
 Vector3 up(0, 1, 0);
 Vector3 rights = forwards.crossProduct(up); 
 Vector3 position(0, 0, 0);

switch (special_key)
{
case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:

    forwards.rotateArbitrary(Vector3::UNIT_Y_PLUS, 0.1);
    rights.rotateArbitrary(Vector3::UNIT_Y_PLUS, 0.1);
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
    forwards.rotateArbitrary(Vector3::UNIT_Y_PLUS, -0.1);
    rights.rotateArbitrary(Vector3::UNIT_Y_PLUS, -0.1);
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_UP:
    forwards.rotateArbitrary(rights, 0.1);
    up.rotateArbitrary(rights, 0.1);
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
    forwards.rotateArbitrary(rights, -0.1);
    up.rotateArbitrary(rights, -0.1);
    break;
    // add more cases here
}

glLoadIdentity();
Vector3 look_at = position + forwards;
gluLookAt(position.x, position.y, position.z,
    look_at.x, look_at.y, look_at.z,
    up.x, up.y, up.z);
```

Comment: What exactly did you try to achieve that? What got you stuck?

Comment: Thank you, but i was able to get it

Comment: If you have found a solution then please create an answer here to help others with a similar problem and also to make a nice Q/A pair.